# Powershell outputs strange output

Tags: powershell, object, addition

I'm making a function to create a custom object and I'm rather new to powershell.
The thing is - I'm getting digits in the powershell command whish I don't want and think that I'm doing it wrong.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
function Create_object{
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$global:combo1_info = @()
    $combo1_query = QR "SELECT DISTINCT company FROM machine"
    if ($combo1_query.Text.Length -gt 0){
        $a = 0
        $combo1_query | ForEach-Object{
            $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Id = $a
                Company = $_.company
            }
            $script:combo1_info.Add($obj)
            $a = $a + 1
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get in is :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

When I do a `$combo1_info | Format-Table -Wrap` I got the correct table but don't know why I get the leading digits when it's created by `"$script:combo1_info.Add($obj)"`

PS : the custom `function QR SELECT DISTINCT company FROM machine` is working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try not to use global variables.  Second when you have a dynamic array you should use `List`.  The Array was meant for fix size arrays.

Like this:

```
$combo1_info = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$combo1_info.Add($obj)
 # If you really want an array just covert it
$combo1_info.ToArray()
```

Your function would look like this:

```
function Create_object{
    $combo1_info = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    $combo1_query = QR "SELECT DISTINCT company FROM machine"
    if ($combo1_query.Text.Length -gt 0){
        $a = 0
        $combo1_query | ForEach-Object{
            $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Id = $a
                Company = $_.company
            }
            combo1_info.Add($obj)
            $a = $a + 1
        }
    }
    $combo1_info.ToArray()
    return $combo_info
}
```

If you really really ... really want to use your code you can add `$null` which supresses the output (the output is there to show you the size of the array):

```
$script:combo1_info.Add($obj) | $null
```

Comment: Thanks, this totaly works.
Also for the explanation.
could you clarify why I shoudn't use globals?

Comment: @hexedecimal The issue I feel here is the issue of scope.  When an error occurs it will be much harder to find when you use globals.  It would take quite long time for me to explain it and somebody did that job already.  If you are intrested you should read - http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad